# How can I paint terrain with normal map?

Tags: normals, texture-painting, normal-map

How can I paint terrain with normal map? In texture paint mode I can choose one texture to paint, but what if I have a pair of texture? (color + bump)

For example I have a pebbles looping texture. It would be great if I could also make a big bump map as I paint the pebbles.